# how can add new row in react table. In one row must be react-select. Once values are selected from default row further labels are filled

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-table

I want to add a new row to the table with a selection of options in one cell and automatic loading of the remaining cells
I want to add a new a row once '+' button is clicked.
adds a new row, but I can't fill in the data automatically. i don't need to save it right away, saving will be on click save btn

```
const fooTable = ({ state, deleteButtonClick }) => {
  const [data, setData] = state;
  const [newData, setNewData] = useState({
    id: '',
    class: '',
    code: null,
    text: '',
  });

  const handleSelect = selected => {
    const {
      id,
      desc: { class, text },
    } = selected;
    setNewData({ id, class, code: selected, text });
  };

  const addNewData = () => {
    const newDataRow = {
      id: '',
      desc: {
        class: '',
        code: (
          <Select
            options={options}
            getOptionLabel={option => option.desc.code}
            placeholder={null}
            isSearchable={false}
            onChange={handleSelect}
            menuPortalTarget={document.body}
          />
        ),
        text: '',
      },
    };
    setNewData(prev => {
      return [...prev, newDataRow];
    });
  };
```

[image]

I want to add a new a row once '+' button is clicked.
adds a new row, but I can't fill in the data automatically. i don't need to save it right away, saving will be on click

Comment: I forgot to add, I'm quite a beginner

Comment: I think you are not supposed to use the word `class` when creating a `const` because `class`  is reserved as a future keyword by the `ECMAScript` specification